# Unable to make the complete image clickable in wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I'm creating a website in WordPress and have used some plugins now trying to modify the codes as per the need.

```
<?php
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit;
}
global $property, $post;
$property = opalesetate_property(get_the_ID());
?>
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Property" <?php post_class('property-mark-hover-item'); ?>>
    <div class="property-grid">
        <div class="property-box-image-wrapper">
            <?php opalestate_get_loop_thumbnail(opalestate_get_option('loop_image_size', 'large')); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="property-grid__content">


            <div class="entry-content">
                <div class="property-price-wrapper"><?php opalestate_property_loop_price(); ?></div>
                <?php the_title('<h5 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url(get_permalink()) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h5>'); ?>

                <div class="property-address">
                    <?php if ($property->latitude && $property->longitude) : ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url($property->get_google_map_link()); ?>" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
                            <span class="property-view-map"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></span>
                             <?php if ($property->get_address()) : ?>
                                <span class="property-address__text"><?php echo esc_html($property->get_address()); ?></span>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </a>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                </div>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->

            <?php opalestate_get_loop_short_meta(); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="property-group-label">
            <?php opalestate_property_featured_label(); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="property-options">
                <?php if (($count = $property->get_gallery_count()) && $count > 1) : ?>
                    <a href="#view-gallery" class="opalestate-ajax-gallery" data-id="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>"><i class="fullhouse2-icon-camera-alt"></i></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>

        <?php do_action('opalestate_after_property_loop_item'); ?>
    </div>    <!-- .property-grid -->
    <meta itemprop="url" content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"/>
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

In the code above, when someone click on the text only then it's clickable but not on the entire box (image + text).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vK9r.png)

What I'm looking for: If someone click anywhere in the box the link will open.

Comment: Hard to tell what is what from the screenshot, but I am guessing you should probably move the `opalestate_get_loop_thumbnail(...)` call _inside_ of the link that you are creating ...?

Comment: @CBroe Only the text is clickable in the screenshot you have seen, I'm trying to make even the image too clickable (or you can say everything should be clickable).   https://demo.bookyourghar.com/

Comment: Okay, the image is already contained in a link. But it is not clickable, because the `::before` element of the container is absolutely positioned on top of it. You can add `pointer-events: none;`, then it will let pass clicks through to the link below it. But then it will still only work for the upper half, the lower half is still covered by the `.property-grid__content` element, and only part of that is a link. If you want the full think clickable, then you should perhaps make _that_ a link, instead of only linking part of its content.